# Is property Length in static string calculated in runtime or during compilation?

Tags: c#, performance

If I have this code

```
if ("test".Length == 4)
```

does it even ever calculate this `Length` or compiler calculate it and use a number in IL code?

If it's done runtime it means the code that contains such things is slower than if it contained the number.

for example

```
int length = 2 + 4;
```

would be faster than

```
int length = 2 + "test".Length;
```

this is what I would like to know

edit: per rant I have benchmarked this myself, and it seems to run same fast, however I don't understand why, given the replies that are telling me it's producing 2 different IL codes?

So is it safe to use this in code without decreasing performance at all?

Comment: This is beyond micro optimization. It will be very hard (rare) to find production code where this is an issue.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my platform, code compiled with VS 2010 for .NET 4, IL DASM shows

#### Debug

```
...
IL_0001:  ldstr      "test"
IL_0006:  callvirt   instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::get_Length()
...
```

#### Release

```
...
IL_0000:  ldstr      "test"
IL_0005:  callvirt   instance int32 [mscorlib]System.String::get_Length()
...
```

Which means no compile time optimization. However, CLR jitter may optimize this. It's possible to see the result of such optimization by looking at Assembly code, here is the result

[image]

On my platform, code compiled in Release for `x86` platform appear to do run time comparison and jitter did not optimize the code.

The code I used

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if ("test".Length == 4) { }
    }
}
```

And this is the part of Assembly code generate for the `if` block. Value for the `test` string is compared on line `17`.

```
if ("test".Length == 4)
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  sub         esp,8 
00000006  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx 
00000009  cmp         dword ptr ds:[00148ED4h],0 
00000010  je          00000017 
00000012  call        5D664D0A 
00000017  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[035F2188h] 
0000001d  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
0000001f  call        5D4CA74B 
00000024  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax 
00000027  nop
```

Comment: Sure you can check. Just descend to the x86 level.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thank you for reviewing this. I added assembly code. It looks as if no optimization has been performed on my platform.

Answer (score 1):

I just compiled it in LINQPad, here's the generated IL.

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       "test"
IL_0006:  callvirt    System.String.get_Length
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.4    
IL_000C:  ceq
```

So it appears it's done at run-time. The result is the same with and without compiler optimization turned on.

And yes indeed, when the C# compiler is able to convert `2 + 4` to `ldc.i4.6`, but `2 + "test".Length` requires a function call. But, as others have pointed out the JIT compiler may be able to do more optimizations on this code than the C# compiler does.

Comment: with compiler optimization?

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly With and without. Same generated IL

Comment: wow that actually means that doing this is a bad thing. I was thinking that such a code is same fast

Comment: Note that this is all about the C# compiler. No telling what the Jitter makes of it.